# Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-config wasm) in yarn prisma

Tags: compiler-errors, prisma, yarn-v2

I am trying to run Calc.com app.
so I installed pgsql and then cloned calc.com
And I run like this

```
yarn
```

and then

```
yarn workspace @calcom/prisma db-deploy
```

Reference :[Calc.com in Github](https://github.com/calcom/cal.com)

But I got error
[image]

Comment: Have you added DATABASE_URL in .env file?

Comment: yes of course DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/postgres"

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I was using windows system.
how I solved it was

1. copy `DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:@localhost:5450/calends"` this URL from main .env(in root folder).
2. Past in into `packages\prisma\.env` below ../../.env line

Answer (score 1):

This is not able to find your `.env` file and variable DATABASE_URL.

Keep your `DATABSE_URL` variable in the `.env` file, not other dotenv files.